# Editing an asp label from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, label

I am trying to set a text to an asp label from javascript, this is what i tried but it doesnt work

```
document.getElementById("Label1").value = "new text value";

 <asp:Label ID="Label1" name="Label1" Font-Size="XX-Large" runat="server" Text="I am just testing"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: If you're using .net 4 then add ClientIdMode="Static" to your label control - if not add <%=Label1.ClientID%> within your getElementById statement. See this resource for deeper explanation. http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

Comment: `.textContent` is the standard property for getting/changing the text but some older browsers don't support that which is why other people have been suggesting `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:-

```
 document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").value = "new text value";
```

or you can try

```
 var elMyElement = document.getElementByID('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');

  elMyElement.innerHTML = "your text here";
```

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET changes "Label1" to something like MasterPageContent_Label1 when rendered to the client. Also ASP.NET Label controls are renderd to the client as `<span>` elements so you need to use innerHTML as opposed to value to set the content.

```
document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "new text value";
```

Answer (score 2):

`Label1` is the server side ID of the Label control. Use the `ClientID` to access it from the javascript. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").innerHTML= "new text value";
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the *ClientID* of the control in order to manipulate it in JavaScript.

The [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) is the `Id` that gets rendered in the browser.

```
document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").value = "new text value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  `document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').InnerHTML = "Your Text Changed";`

Answer (score 1):

Use..

```
document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').innerText="New Text Value" ;
```

Comment: and should i define the label in the code behind... because there an exception "Label1 does not exist in this context"

Comment: Use ClientID mode as Predictable...see this article this may help you...http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/we-lovenet-4-clean-web-control-ids-with-clientidmode-property-to-static-and-predictable

Answer (score 1):

The asp.net label is rendered as a span so you need to set its innerHTML property not the value property, another option is to use JQuery and use the .text() method